# Can you use soapui to automate functional tests to run multiple tests in one instance?

Tags: web-services, automated-tests, soapui

from what I've seen online functional test can be automated to send a request through the soapui harness and a response can be verified. But could I use soapui to write a hundred tests and have these all automatically run and record a response with no user interaction?

Please note I don't have access to soapui pro, only the free version.

Comment: https://learnsoapui.wordpress.com/2012/05/19/groovy-datasource-teststep-dataloop-teststep-using-groovy-in-soapui/   -- is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a test suite in soap-ui, inside test suite you can define all your test cases.When you execute the test suite, all your test will run in a single shot.You can put assertions to validate these response.

Answer (score 0):

A hundred test cases huh?? In the free version you don't have any inbuilt SOAPUI steps fro data driven testing which is not a good thing. But certainly not impossible to achieve. You need to write groovy codes [kind of like JAVA, but as a script] to achieve it. For e.g., if you have your data in an excel, each row as one test case, write a groovy code to fetch data from each row and send it to the request, then to capture the response and then a code to increment the row and loop through all the steps conditionally. These things can be easily done in the PRO version.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just set the suite to run the tests in parallel?

[image]